# Running pwsh in iTerm2 error zsh: command not found: pwsh but works in default MacOSX Terminal

Tags: powershell, zshrc

The problem is that I am getting a zsh: command not found: pwsh when trying to run pwsh in iTerm2. This works in native OSX Sonoma terminal and no idea how to fix this for iTerm2.

I tried to fix this part in my iTerm2 pathway to this path located below.

```
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin/"
```

Comment: If it works in `Terminal.app`, run `pwsh -c '$PSHOME'` there, which will tell you PowerShell's installation directory.

Answer (score -1):

If subprocess is applied, you have to check python whether it is compatible with your machine. Uninstall the old environment and after restarting install the recent python environment. Then check whether it is working. If there is still no improvement don't be worried, just check programming libraries or frameworks one by one by testing.

Or check whether different shell or profile file than the native OSX terminal, or the PATH variable being set differently in iTerm2.

Comment: Python is unrelated to the question at hand.

Comment: Sometime python behaves newly by making machines to respond its style if not compatible and it impacts other environ.

Comment: Im not asking about python